# JQuery/JavaScript detect index of button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got several buttons that look like:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Scan
  </a>
</span>
```

But I need to be able to detect which of the x number of buttons has been pressed. Is there any way I can do that with JQuery/JavaScript?

The buttons are created dynamically like:

```
$('input[role="barcode"]').before('<span class="input-group-btn"><a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Scan</a></span>')
```

As an alternative is it possible to give each button a different id or href to differentiate between them on creation?

Comment: you can create an counter and add it to your elemnts id attribute

Comment: You need delegate 'click' event to parent container of buttons. Second you need mark each button by index, you can use #id, .class, data-property. And listen on container target of event click

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: These are not buttons. This is a button: `<button>...</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try $.index();

```
$('.btn-default').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    alert(index);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7daffjh8/18/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[role="barcode"]').each( function(index, elem) {
  $(this).before(
     '<span class="input-group-btn">'
    +  '<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-index="' + index + '">'
    +    '<i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Scan'
    +  '</a>'
    + '</span>'
  );
});

$(document).on('click', 'a.btn', function () {
  console.log('You clicked on link with index', this.getAttribute("data-index"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect which button was clicked in the event handler:

```
$('.input-group-btn').click(function(e){
    var index = $(e.target).index();
    console.log(index);
});
```

Comment: `e.target` returns a dom node not a jQuery object. See https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other described JQUERY methods OR

You can yourself give a manual number to button while creating like

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <a class="btn btn-default" index="1" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Scan
  </a>
</span>
```

**OR Using JS like**

```
for(i=0 to n){
  var l_button = document.createElement("Button");
  l_button.setAttribute("index",i);
}
```

And when you want to **retrieve** the index you can do like:

```
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
var index_val = target.getAttribute("index");
```